# File Upload: Check for file format and then invoke srvlet

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, servlets

I have a JSP code for file upload. I have given the servlet path in the action attribute of form.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    background-color: #CCCCFF;
}

</style>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Upload Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
    <h1 align="center" >Status Of Metadata Components<br><br></h1>
    <P> Upload the Package.xml File</P>
    <form method="post" action="Testservlet"
        enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select file to upload: <input type="file" name="file" size="60" /><br />
        <br /> <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I want to check if the file uploaded is of the type '.xml' and then redicrect to 'testservlet', if not i want to stay on same page. How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of simple js method you can check the extension of the file.

 On form submit call the js method & then using split get the extension if extension!="xml" return false which will not allow control to go to your servlet.
 Check the code

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function checkFile()
{
        var name = document.getElementById("file").value;
        var extension = name.split(".");
        if(extension[1]!="xml")
            {
                alert("Incorrect file");
                return false;
            }               

        else
            {
                alert("Correct file");
                return true;
            }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="TestServlet" method="post" onsubmit="return checkFile()">
Select file to upload: <input type="file" name="file" id="file" size="60"   />
    <br/><input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Upload">


</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tried it, but it doesnt seem to be working, looks like the function call is not happening

Comment: It's working for me. Said incorrect file for .png file, and then correct file for .xml and then TestServlet not found. So the code is correct.